# How can I split a complicated line into different fill-able groups?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fill, line-art

I'm working with Adobe Illustrator for the first time, and I'm coming across something that I think it can do, but I can't find the right Google-words to find it.

Ok, first, here's an image to show you the kind of thing that I'm working with:

[image: swirly-image]

A link to the zipped version of my svg can be found [here](https://jonathanwhitmore.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/ex1.svg_.zip) or a pdf version [here](https://jonathanwhitmore.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/ex1.pdf) to see my starting point.

So, to my eye, there are obvious places where one could, in principle, use the Live Paint Bucket Tool to fill regions with color. Of course, when I try to do that directly, it tells me:

[image]

What I'm stuck on is how to split this line into a bunch of different fill-able islands. And, hopefully, this process is something that's reasonably able to be quick as in, select all, split into islands, and it's done. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Select the shape
- Swap the Fill and Stroke, so it has a **fill and no stroke**
- Hit the **Divide** button on the **Pathfinder Panel** (Window > Pathfinder)
- Fill to your heart's content (You could then use Live Paint or merely the Direct Selection Tool and click sections to alter their fill color.)

[image]

Comment: This is wonderful, thank you! Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Glad I could help `:)`